# ANR on art::DexFile::FindClassDef(art::dex::TypeIndex)

Tags: android, performance, dex, android-anr-dialog, anr

Firebase Crashlytics reported an ANR which I couldn't find out what is causing the issue.
It appears that there is something wrong with ArtDexFileLoader.

```
main (native):tid=1 systid=10067 
#00 pc 0x18de0 libdexfile.so (art::DexFile::FindClassDef(art::dex::TypeIndex) const + 30)
#01 pc 0x2484d libdexfile.so (art::dex::DexFileVerifier::CheckInterClassDefItem() + 536)
#02 pc 0x2594d libdexfile.so (art::dex::DexFileVerifier::CheckInterSectionIterate(unsigned int, unsigned int, art::DexFile::MapItemType) + 216)
#03 pc 0x25b1f libdexfile.so (art::dex::DexFileVerifier::CheckInterSection() + 186)
#04 pc 0x25c1f libdexfile.so (art::dex::DexFileVerifier::Verify() + 130)
#05 pc 0x26219 libdexfile.so (art::dex::Verify(art::DexFile const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, char const*, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*) + 140)
#06 pc 0x1c2db libdexfile.so (art::DexFileLoader::OpenCommon(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, art::OatDexFile const*, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFileContainer, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFileContainer> >, art::DexFileLoader::VerifyResult*) + 198)
#07 pc 0x15ea7 libdexfile.so (art::ArtDexFileLoader::OpenOneDexFileFromZip(art::ZipArchive const&, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, art::DexFileLoaderErrorCode*) const + 686)
#08 pc 0x159cf libdexfile.so (art::ArtDexFileLoader::OpenAllDexFilesFromZip(art::ZipArchive const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> > > >*) const + 298)
#09 pc 0x157cb libdexfile.so (art::ArtDexFileLoader::OpenZip(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> > > >*) const + 154)
#10 pc 0x15531 libdexfile.so (art::ArtDexFileLoader::OpenWithMagic(unsigned int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> > > >*) const + 208)
#11 pc 0x1543d libdexfile.so (art::ArtDexFileLoader::Open(char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<art::DexFile const, std::__1::default_delete<art::DexFile const> > > >*) const + 96)
#12 pc 0x3ac709 libart.so (art::OatFileManager::OpenDexFilesFromOat(char const*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, art::OatFile const**, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >*) + 3032)
#13 pc 0x373a09 libart.so (art::DexFile_openDexFileNative(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jstring*, int, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*) + 92)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native method)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:109)
       at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
       at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:439)
       at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:398)
       at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:129)
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:104)
       at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
       at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
       at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
       at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
       at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:907)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:964)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1196)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2672)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2664)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6921)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:263)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2057)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8097)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Since there isn't any reference to my codes or any other 3rd party libraries that I used, I don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: Is this just a report from one device? Which model? The stack trace looks pretty normal, so the problem may be the device itself. Do you know is the device is in genuine/stock state or rooted? Because in a rooted device my suspicion would be that some tracing software is running which delays everything.

Comment: @Robert No but it only happens in android 11, most of the cases are happening on Oppp devices but there are reports from other brands too (85% are from Oppo).

Comment: @Robert devices such as Redmi 9A, galaxy A11, galaxy a12, galaxy a02, Redmi 10A, Oppo A54, Oppo A16 (e, k)
Also all of them are not rooted

Comment: I assume it happens at app start. Have you checked the APK file how many dex files it contains and their size? I would also try to check the code that causes the class loading in `ContextImpl.createAppContext`. In AOSP source code you may get which class should be loaded. Sk in the end you could trace in which DEX file it is located.

Comment: @Robert I've checked the apk dex files, there are 14 files with size range [1.5MB, 5.9MB] average 3.5MB. I didn't understand your second suggestion. can yo elaborate more?